# How do I use LINQ-to-Entities to insert Customers Order Details into my Bill Table

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, linq-to-entities

Kindly help me with this.

I am creating a Shop management application using window forms to manage a baby shop. All aspects work except adding customer order details to the database.

So far I used the ode below to add customer bill which contains all the items he or she wants to purchase.

```
 private void btuAddBill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtProName.Text != "" && txtProPrice.Text != "")
        {
            if (ComboSelectCustID.Text != "NONE")
            {
                if (txtQuantity.Text != "")
                {
                    decimal Total = Convert.ToDecimal(txtProPrice.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(txtQuantity.Text);
                    DataGridViewRow newRow = new DataGridViewRow();
                    newRow.CreateCells(DataGribBills);
                    newRow.Cells[0].Value = n + 1;
                    newRow.Cells[1].Value = txtProName.Text;
                    newRow.Cells[2].Value = txtProPrice.Text;
                    newRow.Cells[3].Value = txtQuantity.Text;
                    newRow.Cells[4].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtProPrice.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(txtQuantity.Text);
                    DataGribBills.Rows.Add(newRow);
                    n++;
                    
                    GrdTotal = GrdTotal + Total;
                    txtTotalAmt.Text = Convert.ToString(GrdTotal);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Kindly Input Quantity to Proceed");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Kindly Select Customer ID");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Kindly Select Product");
        }
    }
```

When the customer is ready to pay, the transaction is processed and the total bill amount is sent to the database with a few details about the transaction.

below is the code I use to post the transaction to my database. This transaction contains only the total price of the list of items bought along with the total quantity.

```
private void btuAddTransaction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TotaPurchaseAmt = Convert.ToDecimal(txtQuantity.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(txtPurchaseCost.Text);
        decimal profit = GrdTotal - TotaPurchaseAmt;
        DBS = new BabyHubEntities();
        ProductTB del = new ProductTB();
        decimal proID = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTbale_ID.Text);
        cusQua = Convert.ToDecimal(txtQuantity.Text);
        var IDpro = (from s in DBS.ProductTBs where s.t_ID == proID select s).FirstOrDefault();

        IDpro.ProdQty = IDpro.ProdQty - Convert.ToDecimal(txtQuantity.Text);
        if (cusQua > IDpro.ProdQty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Qunatity is not in stock");
        }
        else
        {
            DBS.SaveChanges();
            if (txtBill_ID.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Missing Transaction Details");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    DBS = new BabyHubEntities();
                    BillingTB acc = new BillingTB();
                    ProfitTB PS = new ProfitTB();

                    acc.bill_ID = Convert.ToDecimal(hidetxtHideID.Text);
                    acc.Biiling_ID = txtBill_ID.Text;
                    acc.billDate = DateTime.Now;
                    acc.customerID = ComboSelectCustID.Text;
                    acc.customerName = txtCustName.Text;
                    acc.EmplName = MainLogin.TBH_Login.Username;
                    acc.Amt = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalAmt.Text);

                    string message = "Are you sure you want to add this Transaction?";
                    string title = "Adding Record...";
                    MessageBoxButtons but = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
                    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(message, title, but);
                    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        acc.SellerName = MainLogin.TBH_Login.Username;
                        DBS.BillingTBs.Add(acc);
                        DBS.SaveChanges();
                        MessageBox.Show("Transaction Added Successfully");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Transaction Not Added");
                    }

                    PS.BillID = txtBill_ID.Text;
                    PS.SoldBy = MainLogin.TBH_Login.Username;
                    PS.SalAmt = GrdTotal;
                    PS.ProfitAmt = profit;
                    PS.SoldQty = Convert.ToDecimal(txtQuantity.Text);
                    PS.SaleDT = DateTime.Now;
                    PS.UnitPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(txtProPrice.Text);
                    PS.ProdPurcCost = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPurchaseCost.Text);
                    DBS.ProfitTBs.Add(PS);
                    DBS.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        DisplayTransaction();
    }
```

Now I will like to send to a different table the Order Details which will include the list of items the customer is buying plus their unit prices, and the quantity, all under one OrderID with order date. This has kept me up for days.

Kindly assist me with this.

Comment: please post the code that communicates with the data base and state precisely the nature of your problem with that.

Comment: @MongZhu thanks for responding to my problem, I have updated the post with that block of code. However, that block of code works perfectly the way I want it. I only want to post to a different table called OrderDetailsTB, the list of items with their unit price and quantity and total, all under the same transaction ID. So that using the Transaction ID, i can fetch from the database list of items a customer bought on a given date